# Beaker with docker and ubuntu-upstart image doesn't start container

Tags: puppet, docker

I am trying to get Beaker to integrate with an Upstart enabled Dockerfile. This is my current nodeset:

```
HOSTS:
    ubuntu-server:
        roles:
         - master
        platform: ubuntu-14.04-x64
        image: ubuntu-upstart:14.04
        hypervisor: docker
        docker_cmd: '/sbin/init'
        docker_preserve_image: true
        docker_image_commands:
         - wget --no-check-certificate https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
         - apt-get install -y wget ca-certificates
         - dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
         - apt-get update
         - apt-get -y install puppet curl ntpdate git ruby
         - "sed --in-place=.bak 's/without-password/yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

CONFIG:
  log_level: verbose
  type: foss
```

The problem is that this container is never started, as seen by `docker ps`. Beaker is also reporting:

node available as `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@0.0.0.0 -p 49204`

```
ubuntu-server 13:40:43$  dpkg -s curl  
Warning: Try 1 -- Host 0.0.0.0 unreachable: connection closed by remote host
Warning: Trying again in 1 seconds
Warning: Try 2 -- Host 0.0.0.0 unreachable: Connection refused - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 49204
Warning: Trying again in 1 seconds
Warning: Try 3 -- Host 0.0.0.0 unreachable: Connection refused - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 49204
Warning: Trying again in 2 seconds
```

If I replace the `docker_cmd` with:

```
docker_cmd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Then it works, but without Upstart (which in turn break tests).

I can do: `docker ps -a` which shows some exited containers with command: `/bin/sh -c /sbin/init`

How can I make beaker honor the `docker_cmd` and not run `/sbin/init` under `/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 1):

in your Gemfile, use this :

```
gem 'beaker', github: 'puppetlabs/beaker', branch: 'master'
```

They fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by replacing

```
docker_cmd: '/sbin/init'
```

with

```
docker_cmd: ['/sbin/init']
```